# How to push the content of a container into an array using Meteor-Dragula?

Tags: javascript, meteor, dragula

I am using [Meteor-Dragula](https://github.com/rfox90/meteor-dragula). Lets says I drag a container that has the String `hello` into the `#right` DOM element. How do I access that string? Say, pushing it into a String array.

Maybe I'm on the right track with something like this?

```
x = [];

Template.dragulaTemplate.events({
  "drop #right1": function(el) {
    x.push(el);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't use Meteor events for [Meteor-Dragula](https://github.com/rfox90/meteor-dragula). Instead, you'll need to use **[`drake.on`](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula#drakeon-events)** in order to register event listeners. For example:

```
x = [];
Template.dragulaTemplate.onRendered(function() {
  var drake = dragula([document.querySelector('#left1'), document.querySelector('#right1')]);
  drake.on('drop', function(el, target, source, sibling) {
    x.push($(el).text());
    console.log(x);
  });
});
```